# How to creat command in Cypress

Tags: javascript, jquery, cypress, autotest

In debugging my Cypress tests I use a command for highlighting the element I am currently working with

```
{CurrentElement}.then($el=> {$el.css('border', '1px solid magenta')})
```

I'd like to create something more informative and short. So I am looking towards the custom command in commands.js. But I was not succed doing this. I was trying to creat custom command in commands.js:

```
Cypress.Commands.add("highlight", $el=> {$el.css('border', '1px solid magenta')})
```

And then to use it in my test in this way:

```
{CurrentElement}.then(highlight())
```

or like this:

```
{CurrentElement}.then(highlight($el))
```

But anytime I get ReferenceError: highlight is not defined. How can I implement the working command for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use the syntax:

`{CurrentElement}.then(highlight($el))`

you don't need a custom command. Just declare `highlight` as a normal function.

However, using a custom command you will be able to write it as follows:

`{CurrentElement}.highlight();`

which IMHO is more elegant.

In order to do so, you need to specify that the command should be applied on an element subject, as follows:

`Cypress.Commands.add("highlight", {prevSubject: 'element'}, $el=> {$el.css('border', '1px solid magenta')});`

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I wanted to get. But what does this magic with prevSubject do? I guess that this is about definition of the $el. But how does it work? I just added return and got a very useful tool.

Answer (score 0):

you should refer to `highlight()` as `cy.highlight()` since it is a method chained of `cy`. So it would look like this:

**Commands.js**

```js
Cypress.Commands.add("highlight", $el=> {$el.css('border', '1px solid magenta')})
```

**spec.js**

```js
{CurrentElement}.then(cy.highlight())
```

Comment: Change `{CurrentElement}.then(highlight())` to `{CurrentElement}.then(cy.highlight())`. I think that should fix the problem.

Comment: the update from Avanthika is correct indeed. I copied your entry but forgot to add the `cy.`...

Comment: If I use via this syntax, I am getting `{CurrentElement}` is not defined. Do I need to do something before using `{CurrentElement}`??